# What are the benefits of nested nodes in a RESTful URL

Tags: api, rest

Can someone please help explain the benefits of designing a RESTful API url the "correct" way:

`/api/companies/1/buildings/4/rooms/420`

vs. the "incorrect" way:

`/api/rooms/420`

The benefits I see:

- easier to read as a sentence
- easier to infer what "lower-level" resources are available (IMO the best reason)

**Q1** Do we assume that room #420 should not exist in any other building? I could argue that it's the db pointer, so maybe that's where I'm confused.

Another thing is that you're not supposed to nest more than a few nodes deep:

`/api/companies/1/buildings/4/rooms/420/desks/5/legs/3`

**Q2:** At what point do you break out these resources? Or does this hint that the API design needs re-thinking if this ever happens?

**Q3:** When designing the front end URL, is it *then* ok to make it just `.com/rooms/420`?

Thanks :)

Comment: REST does not say anything about what URLs should look like. Neither of your examples is more or less RESTful.

Answer (score 1):

URIs are not intended to be "read as sentences". You should consider URIs to be opaque - they do not need to convey hierarchical information. RESTful APIs use links between resources to navigate to other information. Programmers using RESTful APIs use documentation to discern the relationship between resource types.

API clients don't know or care what your `id` is. Maybe it's a database id, maybe not. They just know that the URI `api/rooms/420` is a unique way to identify a specific resource.

Q1. ? Room #420 exists wherever it exists. Stick a `building` link on the `room` resource. Clients can follow that link to see what building a room is in.

Q2. *I* break them out as often as clients will let me. :-) Give that URI, how does a client search for all the rooms with more than two windows, regardless of building? Or all the desks that are marked to be thrown out, regardless of building? Flat APIs give you more flexibility than deeply nested ones.

Q3. It's never not OK. It's however you decide to design it. I'm unclear on what you mean by "the front end URL".